# How can I display the specified icon on the list in "Programs and Features" by the installer created by Inno Setup?

Tags: icons, inno-setup

When installed with the installer created by Inno Setup, the icon specified in the "ICON" section does not appear on the list in "Programs and Features".The specified icon can be displayed on the desktop or startup.
How can I display the specified icon on the list in "Programs and Features" by the installer created by Inno Setup?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a quick search in the help system and found the answer.

You need to use the [`UninstallDisplayIcon`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayicon) keyword in the `[Setup]` section of your script.

The help topic states:

> This lets you specify a particular icon file (either an executable or an .ico file) to display for the Uninstall entry in the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel applet. The filename will normally begin with a directory constant.

Examples:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe,1
```

Please go to the help topic for full details of this keyword.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I solved it.
I specified an .ico file for [UninstallDisplayIcon], but when I replaced it with an executable file, it worked.

Comment: @TakahiroFunahashi Glad my answer helped (although according tot he documentation an ICO file should have been OK). But if it is now working - then good!